# Is there a UML symbol representing instantiation? This one doesn't seem to be one

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, uml

The following figure comes from https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture

[image]

I refer to it as a "figure" rather than a "diagram" as I'm not sure if it is.

the doc/guide says

> Often, each of those is a `ProviderManager`, and they share a parent.

which seems to indicate the 3 blue rectangles labeled `ProviderManager` are instances.

Is my understanding correct? Is this a widely used UML symbol representing instantiation? I googled a little bit but just got lots of hits about class diagram & inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagram in the question doesn't appear to be a UML diagram, at least following the standard. UML does offer the [Object Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram) to show the runtime structure of a system at a specific point in time, which would include multiple instances of an object.

Comment: Yup. In particular, *stereotypes* must be enclosed in guillemets (or in double angle brackets, if guillemets are somehow not possible), so it should be `«parent»` or `<<parent>>` in order to be legal UML, not just `parent`. *Color UML* does seem to be a thing, but there is no color associated with being an instance. There are four colors, representing a moment or duration in time, a role, a description, or a concrete thing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Even before using stereotypes, I'd suspect it would rather be inheritance or realization arrows, or perhaps more general association and dependency arrows. But if you're going to use a stereotype, then yes, you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

### The diagram is about composition, not about inheritance

The term "*parent*" in the diagram  misleads to think that it's about inheritance.  Reading carefully shows that this is in reality about composition:

> (...) each group can have its own dedicated AuthenticationManager. Often, each of those is a `ProviderManager`, and they share a parent. The parent is then a kind of “global” resource, acting as a fallback for all providers.

This is confirmed by the documentation of the [`ProviderManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html), in the general explanations and by deduction from the definition of the constructor.  The design uses in fact a [chain of responsibility pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility), and `parent` relates to the name a private property at the other end.

### The parent *role* in the diagram could be correct UML

In an UML diagram a link (instance of an association) can be represented as a line between two linked objects (instances of a type). `parent` would then be the role of the instance (in practical terms, the name of the property through which you can access it). Links can be directed to represent navigability.  The only minor graphical issue is that the arrows should be open-headed. (you can find example of this notation in the UML 2.5.1 specifications, page 128 and 129)

### Instantiation and UML compliance

Two things makes this diagram artistic and not UML compliant:

- the class names `ProviderManager` and the interface name `AuthenticationManager` are types of anonymous objects and should therefore be preceded by `:` and be underlined.
- the relation between a `ProviderManager` and the `AuthenticationManager`  does neither represent the interface realisation, nor instantiation. By the way it does not either accurately document that many providers can implement one authentication manager interface.

In fact, if an object is at the same time an instance of `ProviderManager` and `AuthenticationManager`, both classifiers should be mentioned comma separated in the same rectangle.  The diagram would look less spectacular:

[image]

There is [no standard notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35198890/3723423) to graphically show that some objects are instances of a class or of a class that implements an interface.  You can however show a dependency (dotted arrow) and make it more specific with a custom stereotype, e.g. `«Instance of»`  (caution: the standard stereotype `«Instantiate»` is not meant for this, but expresses that one classifier creates instances of another classifier).